# how to find a way to pick one word has each column in order to stay one row per each customer?

Tags: sql, oracle

as per sum per heading my question

I am stumped to find query statement in my ORACLE SQL Developer for shorten time as I have huge database and it take time to sorting by individual column with where and join table on each clause statement however it take two hours result outcome differs to testing for one profile customer output which is quicker than whole database.

Purchased table has customer purchased car, so I am trying to get one answer to find out if customer has particular RED colour any car type to output result column regardles past and present transaction.

[Purchased table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Bdg.png)

Data from Purchased table:

Customer_ID Last_Name   First_name  Colour  Car SUV Truck   4WD
50  Smith   John    Black       Yes
50  Smith   John    Red Yes
50  Smith   John    Red         Yes Yes
50  Smith   John    Red Yes
20  McGregor    Katie   Blue    Yes         Yes
20  McGregor    Katie   Red Yes
20  McGregor    Katie   Black       Yes
20  McGregor    Katie   Red Yes         Yes
11  Yang    Karen   Red Yes
11  Yang    Karen   Red     Yes
90  Wilkins Melissa Black   Yes
90  Wilkins Melissa Red         Yes Yes
90  Wilkins Melissa Blue    Yes     Yes
90  Wilkins Melissa Grey
135 Barnes  Tom Red Yes     Yes Yes
135 Barnes  Tom Blue    Yes
135 Barnes  Tom Black           Yes

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVwTA.png)

output result for any red colour car:

Customer_ID Last_Name   First_name  Car SUV Truck   4WD
50  Smith   John    Yes No  No  Yes
20  McGregor    Katie   Yes No  No  No
11  Yang    Karen   Yes Yes No  No
90  Wilkins Melissa No  No  No  Yes
135 Barnes  Tom Yes No  Yes Yes

Thank you for your help

currently I am using below method statements;

WITH

sorted_ as (

select

distinct (colour) ,

customer_id ,

last_name ,

car ,

SUV ,

truck ,

4wd

from purchased)

select

e. customer_id ,

e. last_name ,

nvl (e. car , 'No') car ,

nvl (e. SUV , 'No') SUV ,

nvl (e. truck , 'No') truck ,

nvl (e. 4wd , 'No') 4wd

from (

select

a. customer_id ,

a. last_name ,

a. car ,

b. SUV ,

c. truck ,

d. 4wd

from (

select

distinct(car),

customer_id

from sorted_

where colour = 'Red'

and car = 'Yes') a

left join (

select

distinct(SUV),

customer_id

from sorted_

where colour = 'Red'

and SUV = 'Yes') b

ON a. customer_id = b. customer_id

left join (

select

distinct(truck),

customer_id

from sorted_

where colour = 'Red'

and truck = 'Yes') c

ON a. customer_id = c. customer_id

left join (

select

distinct(4wd),

customer_id

from sorted_

where colour = 'Red'

and 4wd = 'Yes') d

ON a. customer_id = d. customer_id

) e

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @J_H ok... how to make it table in typing box, as I tried to finding help on this website not much luck finding only I can think of screenshot to show an example table and out put table

Comment: Type three backticks (```), copy-n-paste some sqlplus SELECT text output, three more backticks, and you're done. See e.g. the tabular data appearing in Littlefoot's answer. Indenting 4 spaces has the same effect, and CTRL-K can help with that.

Comment: @J_H thank you again alas my personal laptop is mac need to find out later if ctrl-k compatible with cmd-k

Comment: You're asking about something that google tells us is well documented: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood what you want, but desired output (screenshot you posted) doesn't match. For example, McGregor has two "Red" rows with car and 4WD marked as such, while your output says that "Yes" is set to car only. Why? I can't run query you posted as it is invalid and - thus - returns *nothing* at all.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From purchased;

CUSTOMER_ID LAST_NAME  FIRST_NAME COLOU CAR SUV TRUCK FOURWD
----------- ---------- ---------- ----- --- --- ----- -------
         50 Smith      John       Black     Yes
         50 Smith      John       Red   Yes
         50 Smith      John       Red           Yes   Yes
         50 Smith      John       Red   Yes
         20 McGregor   Katie      Blue  Yes           Yes 
         20 McGregor   Katie      Red   Yes                   --> car is red
         20 McGregor   Katie      Black     Yes
         20 McGregor   Katie      Red   Yes           Yes     --> car and 4WD are red
         11 Yang       Karen      Red   Yes
         11 Yang       Karen      Red       Yes
         90 Wilkins    Melissa    Black Yes
         90 Wilkins    Melissa    Red           Yes   Yes
         90 Wilkins    Melissa    Blue  Yes     Yes
         90 Wilkins    Melissa    Grey
        135 Barnes     Tom        Red   Yes     Yes   Yes
        135 Barnes     Tom        Blue  Yes
        135 Barnes     Tom        Black         Yes

17 rows selected.
```

Query, as I understood it:

```
SQL> select customer_id, last_name, first_name,
  2    max(case when colour = 'Red' then nvl(car, 'No') end) as car,
  3    max(case when colour = 'Red' then nvl(suv, 'No') end) as suv,
  4    max(case when colour = 'Red' then nvl(truck, 'No') end) as truck,
  5    max(case when colour = 'Red' then nvl(fourwd, 'No') end) as fourwd
  6  From purchased
  7  where colour = 'Red'
  8  group by customer_id, last_name, first_name
  9  /

CUSTOMER_ID LAST_NAME  FIRST_NAME CAR SUV TRUCK FOURWD
----------- ---------- ---------- --- --- ----- -------
         50 Smith      John       Yes No  Yes   Yes
         20 McGregor   Katie      Yes No  No    Yes
         11 Yang       Karen      Yes Yes No    No
         90 Wilkins    Melissa    No  No  Yes   Yes
        135 Barnes     Tom        Yes No  Yes   Yes

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you yes, you are correct and I apologies for my oversight in typing the output

I tried my end to use max as per your suggestion seems it didn't work despite being a bit similar to my question 

let me think of another way mock an example can't use my work example due to highly sensitive matter

still, I want to pick any YES on each column to output one row output (not duplicates) per each profile which is not about the red colour

Comment: ^@Littlefoot sorry I forgot to add your name above my comment after its expiry edit time


Also other things, could you tell me how to work in typing box to make that layout format plz?

Comment: yes your answer is worked using " MAX(case when xxx then xxx else xxx end) as xxx ".
never knew that max not just for number/date and other words works too.
thank you again for your help